Multi-criteria search query optimization in MySQL
I'm using MySQL 8.0.35 and I've two tables in my database: users and clients. Users can be searched by username, firstname, lastname, email, phone, document or even id. The clients table is used to track which users are clients of a specific business, with different statuses indicating their client state:

If a user does not appear, it means they have never been a client.
status = 1 indicates that they are pending.
status = 2 means they are currently a client.
status = 0 means they were a client at some point but are no
longer a client now.

I don’t know the exact input the user will provide. There's no option for them to specify if they are searching by email, document or other fields. I perform some checks before querying to determine the data type but it's mostly based on the input characteristics (like checking for an @ for emails or numeric only for phone numbers and documents). Here are the table structures and the current queries I use for various search inputs:
`Db`.`users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  `document` CHAR(11) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `document_UNIQUE` (`document` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

`Db`.`clients` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NULL,
  `userId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `businessId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `userId`, `businessId`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_clients_users1_idx` (`userId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_clients_business1_idx` (`businessId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clients_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `Db`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clients_business1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`businessId`)
    REFERENCES `Db`.`business` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Query without input:
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.phone 
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.userId = u.id 
WHERE c.businessId = 1 AND c.status = 2 
ORDER BY c.id DESC

Query with numeric input:
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.phone 
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.userId = u.id 
WHERE c.businessId = 1 AND c.status = 2 AND (u.id = $search OR u.document = $search OR u.phone = $search) 
ORDER BY c.id DESC

Query with email input (input contains @):
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.phone 
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.userId = u.id 
WHERE c.businessId = 1 AND c.status = 2 AND u.email = '$search' 
ORDER BY c.id DESC

Query with alphanumeric input (username, firstname, lastname):
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.phone 
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.userId = u.id 
WHERE c.businessId = 1 AND c.status = 2 AND (u.username LIKE '$search%' OR CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) LIKE '$search%' OR u.lastname LIKE '$search%')
ORDER BY c.id DESC


Which indexes should I create to optimize these queries? Do I need
an index on status as well considering it's used in almost every
query? (I filter several other queries by status as well)

Given that I'm currently using LIKE for partial matches, is it
better to switch to full-text search for performance reasons? Should
I consider creating a fullName column and indexing it for such
searches? Previously I was using LIKE with a wildcard % both before and after the input for partial matching. To improve performance, I changed it to use the wildcard only at the end, which already helped to some extent.

I've read that using the OR operator can be less efficient. Should
I consider using a UNION instead, where each part of the search
criteria is handled in a separate query combined with UNION?


Any advice on how to best optimize these queries and indexing strategies would be greatly appreciated. I understand there are several alternatives such as Elasticsearch, Algolia, etc. but I would like to extract as much as possible through MySQL. Thanks!

Your script is open to SQL Injection Attack.
Even if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!
You should always use prepared parameterized statements
in either the MYSQLI_ or PDO API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a ' in a text string like O'Neal.

@RiggsFolly thank you for the advice! Yes, I use prepared statements internally, but I've put the values ​​directly in the queries here just to simplify the examples

All your queries will be helped by an index on clients(businessId, status). You can reverse the order of those two columns if you prefer.
CREATE INDEX business_id_status ON client(businessId, status);

The other indexes you have look like they might be useful. Suggest you use EXPLAIN ANALYZE (just ANALYZE on MariaDB) to look at the execution plans for these queries and see whether any of them do full scans. If they do, you may need another index.
Read this to learn about this topic https://use-the-index-luke.com/

In my case businessId already has an index through the INDEX "fk_clients_business1_idx" ("businessId" ASC) VISIBLE snippet used when creating the table. In this case, would it be enough for me to just add the index for status or should I explicitly inform that the new index will use the businessId column as you recommended in (businessId, status)? It is also worth noting that in most cases the percentage of rows with c.status = 2 will be at least 85% for each business. BTW thanks for the use-the-index-luke recommendation, I'm already learning a lot of valuable details there :)

You should add the compound index I suggested and drop the index on just businessId. The FK doesn’t need the precise index you have, just an index starting with that column.

INDEX(businessid, status) is likely to be great for the first (no input) query.
What percentage of rows have c.businessId = 1 AND c.status = 2?  If it is a large percentage,  may be shunned as being not worth using.
Perhaps it is more useful to have multiple indexes on the other table
INDEX(email),
FULLTEXT(username, firstname, lastname)
etc

For FULLTEXT, you need to use MATCH(...) AGAINST (...)`
Also, note that the columns of MATCH must agree with the FULLTEXT index`.  That implies, for example, that you need
FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname)

if you wat to test
MATCH(firstname, lastname) AGAINST(...)

FULLTEXT is usually very fast, and is likely to be used in preference to a regular INDEX.  But be aware of its limitations.  I suspect than "James, Richard" and "Richards, James" would be synonymous.
(Having 5 UNIQUE indexes (including the PK) on a table is unusual, but not impossible.)

In most cases the percentage of rows with c.status = 2 will be at least 85% for each business. I added the index this way ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX 'user_name_search_idx' (firstname, lastname, username) and what I found curious was that just by creating this index, performance improved a lot (even though I was still using LIKE). When I replaced LIKE with MATCH(...) AGAINST (...), performance remained good but the results returned were not as satisfactory as when using LIKE. Is there any problem using the index initially created for FULLTEXT for filtering with LIKE?

(I don't think there is any connection between FULLTEXT and LIKE.)
